# Is it ok to break the "is a" relationship if I just want part of a class' functionality?

Tags: java, coding-style

I asked a question about extending TreeMaps into "sort by value" TreeMaps on the "code review" site on stackoverflow. Based on the response, I re-wrote the code. I like it. But, it feels like I might be just using tricks. Or, maybe this is a legit way to write software? Can someone please take a look:

```
public class ToolBox {
    public interface SortedMapByValue {
        void put(Object key, Integer val);
        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Integer>> entrySet();        
    }

    public static SortedMapByValue getInstanceSortedMapByValue() {
        class MyComp implements Comparator {
            Map<Object, Integer> sharedMap;

            public int compare(Object key1, Object key2) {
                if(key1.equals(key2)) { return 0; }

                Integer val1 = sharedMap.get(key1);
                Integer val2 = sharedMap.get(key2);

                if(val1 > val2) return -1; 
                return 1;
            }     
        }

        class MyMap<K> extends TreeMap<K, Integer> {
            Map<Object, Integer> sharedMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
            MyMap(Comparator comp) {
                super(comp);
            }

            @Override
            public Integer put(K key, Integer val) {
                if(sharedMap.containsKey(key)) {
                    super.remove(key);
                    val += sharedMap.get(key);
                }
                sharedMap.put(key, val);
                super.put(key, val);
                return val;
            }
        }

        class TreeMapByValue implements SortedMapByValue {
            private MyMap<Object> realMap;

            public TreeMapByValue(MyMap myMap) { this.realMap = myMap; }

            public void put(Object key, Integer val) {
                realMap.put(key, val);
            }

            public Set<Map.Entry<Object, Integer>> entrySet() {
                return realMap.entrySet();
            }
        }

        MyComp myComp = new MyComp();
        MyMap<Object> myMap = new MyMap(myComp);
        myComp.sharedMap = myMap.sharedMap;

        SortedMapByValue treeMapByValue = new TreeMapByValue(myMap);
        return treeMapByValue;
    }
}
```

The question is just whether it is ok to write classes that are fragile and that break super class' apis, as long as you wrap them in a static method? The TreeMapByValue does not break the "is a" relationship with TreeMap only because I hide it. That seems like a trick, but maybe that is a standard way to program? I don't know.

btw: the title refers to my wanting the "red-black" sort algorithm of TreeMap, but I didn't want what the api says regarding sort ordering. I kept the algorithm, but broke the api. But then I hid doing this.

*Please ignore my complete ignorance of generics. I will study them soon enough.*

Comment: You're allowed to do whatever you want inside the implementation class, so long as you conform to the API you're implementing.  The actual behavior doesn't even have to make sense (it won't, if the code contains bugs).  That said, it's probably bad form to inherit from a class when the descendant class won't use its behavior.  What purpose would that serve, other than to confuse the programmer who has to read the code after you write it?

Comment: Well, what I want access to is the black/white sort algorithm in TreeMap. Collections.sort() are (n log(n)). So, TreeMap is just about getting fast sorting.

Comment: whoops. i mean the "red-black tree" sort algorithm of treemap. it is log(n) time. mergesort is (n log(n)).

Comment: This code is too contrived for me to bother deciphering. Is there a reason you can't just *use* a TreeMap instead of extending it?

Comment: @Doval I want a Map that sorts by values (not the keys). And, when keys clash, I want to sum their values. I extend TreeMap just so I can re-use the "red-black" sort algorithm.

Comment: @dwakam I still don't see why you have to extend TreeMap. You can simply put things into it and let it take care of sorting.

Comment: @Doval With each put() into the map there is an invocation of compare(). Within the overridden put(): (1) put the new (key / value) into a shared map. (2) within compare(), all you are passed are keys. But, I am sorting by values. So, in compare() you dip into the shared map to get the values of the keys that were put there in put(). Anyway, I have a very good "interface-only" answer from UnholySampler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyMap` only overrides a single method. The interface implementation does nothing besides delegating to the `MyMap` instance. You could easily just write this in the interface implementation.

```
class TreeMapByValue implements SortedMapByValue, Comparator {
    private Map<Object, Integer> sharedMap;
    private TreeMap<Object, Integer> tree;

    public TreeMapByValue() {
        sharedMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
        tree = new TreeMap<Object, Integer>(this);
    }

    public void put(Object key, Integer val) {
        if(sharedMap.containsKey(key)) {
            tree.remove(key);
            val += sharedMap.get(key);
        }
        sharedMap.put(key, val);
        tree.put(key, val);
        return val;
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<Object, Integer>> entrySet() {
        return realMap.entrySet();
    }


    public int compare(Object key1, Object key2) {
        if(key1.equals(key2)) { return 0; }

        Integer val1 = sharedMap.get(key1);
        Integer val2 = sharedMap.get(key2);

        if(val1 > val2) return -1; 
        return 1;
    }    
}
```

Now you only have one class. There is no shared instance that needs to be explicitly assigned to a different class instance. There isn't a concern about how base class is being overridden. In addition, the factory method isn't needed any more since the initialization isn't multiple steps. If you don't want to expose `compare()`, you can move it into a private inner class.

---

- `sharedMap` and `tree` are bad variable names. The names should provide a description of what they hold or why they are being used.
- Be consistent with your if statements. Sometimes they are one-lined with curly brackets. Sometimes they are one-lined without curly brackets. My preference is to never one-line and always use curly brackets.

Comment: Is passing a reference to "this" during its own construction to the TreeMap constructor an issue? An instance of TreeMap briefly has a reference to an object that is not fully formed. I think I read something about "this" references in constructors, but I'm not sure I understand that issue.

Comment: btw: I like this design a lot. Mine was really hard to keep straight in my head.

Comment: It is possible cause problems when some operations happen during an instances constructor. For example, maybe a member variable hasn't been assigned a value yet when the operation occurs. However, in this case `compare()` only ever interacts with `sharedMap`, which has already been initialized. Additionally, `TreeMap` only stores the reference in its constructor. It doesn't use the `Comparator` until you start dealing with values.

Answer (score 2):

Is a and Has a are reasonable guidelines, very useful when you are learning, but in practice you should never use inheritence unless it's so blatently obvious that it's needed that there is just no question.

Inheritene often seems like a much neater solution, but people who have used it extensively have learned that it leads to difficult to maintain code in the long run.

Comment: This is a little vague unless you go into things like the "fragile base class problem."

Comment: But, the question is more about whether you can just ignore such conventions as long as (1) it is done on a very limited and very contained scale, (2) no other code can access the fragile code. My fragile classes are declared in the constructor method itself.